# MVC 5 generate form data with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I need a way to generate a new unique id for a user when a person focuses out of a textbox.  I am using MVC 5 for this application.  Here is my controller, everything in the controller has been unit tested and it does return the string value that I need.

Controller.  I was able to visit that URL, and I did download a JSON file with the correct data.

```
public ActionResult GetNewId()
{
    string newId = utils.newEmployeeId();
    return Json(new {eId = newId}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Javascript, JQuery call to that controller.  I do not know how to properly reference the ActionResult.  I keep getting undefined errors on eId.

```
$(function () {
    $('#employeeId').focusout(function () {
        if($("#employeeId").val() === "NP")
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Html.ActionLink("GetNewId", "Employees")',
            data: { 'eId': eId },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                $("#employeeId").val(eId);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: can you post example of json that you get in success function?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this. The ID should only be created on the controller when you save the object. (but its `$("#employeeId").val(response.eId);` and delete the `data: { 'eId': eId },` - you not sending anything to the server)

Comment: try   

$("#employeeId").val(response.eId);

Comment: I need to do this because there are a few different employee codes that are used for various reasons.  Employees, Web users, non-persons, and volunteers.  They each need to be prefixed correctly, and unique.

Comment: Successful json download: {"eId":"NP00192"}

Comment: @AWinter, That makes no difference. You must generate your ID when you save the data to the database (any malicious user can easily change the value in your input and change it to whatever they want.. Do not do this!

Comment: I'm not seeing the risk here.  This is a non-primary key value.  I still have server-side validation, this is only being used to prevent users from entering in the same value twice and causing an exception to be thrown.

Comment: I have wrote up some new requirements for this.  I will now provide the user with a dropdown box to select the type of employee they are creating, and creating an id based upon the value selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with yout ajax request:

1.you need to change the url in the reuqest but it like this
    {{yourcontroller}/GetNewId}

2.remove the `"data: { 'eId': eId }"` you dont need it, youre not posting anything to the server.

3. change your `$("#employeeId").val(eId);` to

   `$("#employeeId").val(response.eId);`

this will 100% work